# Can I upgrade the version of Konga Node?

Tags: node.js

I wrote it with a translator, so there may be some parts that are not suitable.

I'm going to use Konga.
Previously, I used the 12.16.3 version of Node, but I ended up using the 18th version.

I'm running into a lot of errors trying to upgrade the Node version.

I wonder if you have tried or succeeded.

The error appears as follows.

```
error: A hook (`helpers`) failed to load! 
debug ... 

error: Failed to lift app: ImplementationError: Failed to load helper `utils` into a Callable!  Sorry, could not interpret "utils" because its underlying implementation has a problem:
------------------------------------------------------
• Missing the `fn` property.
------------------------------------------------------

If you are the maintainer of "utils", then you can change its implementation to solve the problem above.  Otherwise, please file a bug report with the maintainer, or fork your own copy and fix that.
...


error: More details (raw): ImplementationError: Failed to load helper `utils` into a Callable!  Sorry, could not interpret "utils" because its underlying implementation has a problem:
------------------------------------------------------
• Missing the `fn` property.
------------------------------------------------------

If you are the maintainer of "utils", then you can change its implementation to solve the problem above.  Otherwise, please file a bug report with the maintainer, or fork your own copy and fix that.
```

I need help.

I modified the .env file while changing the node version

```
PORT=1337
HOST=localhost
NODE_ENV=development
DB_ADAPTER=postgres
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_URI=postgresql://kong:kong@localhost:5432/kong
DB_USER=kong
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=kong
DB_PASSWORD=kong
KONGA_LOG_LEVEL=debug
TOKEN_SECRET=some_secret_token
```

After that, I replaced the node_module for the 18th version.

And then I ran the command below.

`node ./bin/konga.js  prepare --adapter postgres --uri postgresql://localhost:5432/kong`

And then there was an error

I don't know what else to touch